# Merge multiple dictionaries extracted from MongoDB into a single dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, merge

I am trying to merge multiple dictionaries (around 100) in one.

This is my code to extract 100 articles from mongoDB. Every article is stored inside a dictionary. Thus, I receive 100 dictionaries in the parameter x. Is there any way I can merge all those together? Thank you in advance!

```
print(client)
db = client.ShipShape
print(db)
articles = db.Articles
print(articles)

for x in articles.find({}, {"_id": 0, "text": 1}).limit(100):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Can you provide some example dictionaries from the MongoDB? Also, what is the expected output? Please [edit] your question to include how you want the data to be merged together.

Comment: e.g. { "text": blalalalalalaal}, {"text": gkrojojodd} there are 100 of those dictionaries and i want to ideally return a string or a single dictionary. But when i try to return a string it return only the last article's string not the other 99...

Comment: I think there is a basic misunderstanding of how a [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) works here. the `keys` of a dictionary have to be unique. If you try to to "add" another `key-value` pair to a dictionary where `key` already exists, you will then overwrite the `value` of the old `key` to the new `value`. as in `{"k": 1, "k":2}` will become `{'k': 2}` because the second `k` is being set after the first one, and thus overwriting it.

Comment: That is also the reason why I asked you to [edit] your question to include what the end results (as in, the data-structure you want us to help you achieve) looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to you not giving any additional information really about what "outcome" you want, I can only assume that you want to consolidate the information of "like" keys, to be contained in that same key.

One way to do that is to create a new dictionary where the `value` of the `key` is a list, which you then append new values to:

```py
import pprint

# A list containing dictionaries, which mostly hold the 
# same "keys" as the others
chainOfCommand = [
    {"text": "Been quiet, from ages past", "lorem-ipsum": "Horse"},
    {"text": "We held our peace, condoned our enemies", "lorem-ipsum": "Battalion"},
    {"text": "The desolation, destruction of the nation", "lorem-ipsum": "Glory"},
    {"text": "Enough, can't take it anymore!", "lorem-ipsum": "Seafarer"},
    {"author": "A Hammer that is falling", "lorem-ipsum": "Canine"},
]

mergedChain = {}
# Loop over the dictionaries inside of `chainOfCommand`
for dictionary in chainOfCommand:
    # Loop over each key, value pair of `d`
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        # Using `dict.setdefault`, we can create a default behaviour
        # if the `key` hasn't been inserted into `mergedChain` yet.
        # If it has, then it just returns the value.
        mergedChain.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

# The only reason for using pprint here,
# is to better represent the data.
pprint.pp(mergedChain)
```

Output:

```py
{'text': ['Been quiet, from ages past',
          'We held our peace, condoned our enemies',
          'The desolation, destruction of the nation',
          "Enough, can't take it anymore!"],
 'lorem-ipsum': ['Horse', 'Battalion', 'Glory', 'Seafarer', 'Canine'],
 'author': ['A Hammer that is falling']}
```

See that even though the key `author` was only referenced once in all of the dictionaries, it's still put inside of a `list`.

If you don't care about "duplicates" while looping over `chainOfCommand`, then you can simply do this, to get the "last" value:

```py
mergedChain = {}
for dictionary in chainOfCommand:
    # The `|=` operator for dictionaries is new in Python3.9
    # Use `mergedChain = {**mergedChain, **dictionary}`
    # if you're running an earlier method.
    mergedChain |= dictionary

pprint.pp(mergedChain)
```

Output:

```py
{'text': "Enough, can't take it anymore!",
 'lorem-ipsum': 'Canine',
 'author': 'A Hammer that is falling'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` is the dictionary obtained in each iteration.

```py
 print(client)
 db = client.ShipShape
 print(db)
 articles = db.Articles
 print(articles)

 documentContainer = dict()

 for x in articles.find({}, {"_id": 0, "text": 1}).limit(100):
   documentContainer.update(x)
   print(x)

 print(documentContainer)
```

`documentContainer` will contain the merged dictionary !

Comment: thank you for your help! unfortunately, it returns unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'dict' and 'dict' the text returns dictionaries of articles in the following form: {"text": blablabla}, {"text": lalala} etc etc 100 articles that way :/

Comment: if i put documentContainer={**x} it works but it returns only the last dictionary, not the rest 99. There may be a mongodb function for this.

Comment: Seeing your dictionary response, we can't merge all those dictionaries unless they have different keys.
But, in order to "merge" all those together one can also use arrays, and get the final output as array of objects/dictionaries. 

First define `arr = [ ]` and then doing `arr.append(x)` in place of `documentContainer |= x` should do.

Comment: `|` operator can be used from python3.9 onwards, for merging a dictionary into other. Other options are to use `dic1.update(dic2)` or `dic1 = {**dic1,**dic2} `.

Comment: thanks shyam i did it as a list and now i have one single dict inside the list...great thanks!